# How do I get SVG stroke thickness to work?

Tags: css, svg

Why Isn't the thickness working?

```html
<svg height="80" width="300">
  <path stroke-width="50" d="M 0.269 32.153 L 13.013 2.051 A 3.774 3.774 0 0 1 13.832 0.841 A 3.616 3.616 0 0 1 14.136 0.574 A 3.515 3.515 0 0 1 15.918 0 L 16.406 0 A" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, if you add `stroke="red"` for example, it's definitely there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because the drawing is only using fill, no stroke?

Also, careful, your SVG does not have a `viewBox` defined.